# Find the smallest natural $n$ satisfying three congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, systems-of-equations, congruences

I gotta find the smallest natural number $n$ that satisfies the following conditions: 
$$
3^2|n, \qquad 4^2|(n+1), \qquad 5^2|(n+2).
$$

How would I go about tackling this problem? I need some assistance in how and where to begin.

[3 Expressions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEx1u.png)

Comment: Use the Chinese remainder theorem because your three expressions can be stated as congruences.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) and some computation, we can find that all $n\in{\mathbb N}$ satisfying the given conditions are
$$
n=9\cdot16\cdot25\cdot k+2223, \qquad\mbox{ or }\qquad n=3600k+2223.  \tag{1}
$$
The smallest positive integer of the form $(1)$ is $n=2223$.

But the general solution $(1)$ is *not really needed* if we only want the smallest $n$ satisfying the given congruences. We can find the smallest such $n$ by [applying the Chinese remainder theorem to *two moduli*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Case_of_two_moduli) first, e.g. to $16$ and $25$. Thus we can first find that if $16|(n+1)$ and $25|(n+2)$, then $n$ must have the form:
$$
n=16\cdot25\cdot m+223, \qquad\mbox{ or }\qquad n=400m+223.    \tag{2}
$$
Indeed, $400m+225$ is a multiple of $25$, while
$400m+224$ is a multiple of $16$.
Let's write down a few natural $n$ satisfying $(2)$:
$$
223, 623, 1023, 1423, 1823, 2223, 2623, \ldots
$$ 
Now we simply check that, among the above numbers, the smallest $n$ divisible by $9$ is $n=2223$.